# Entity Framework query to return only partial object graphs

Tags: entity-framework, graph, entity, partial

I'm having a bit of an headache finding a solution for this particular problem.
So here it is:
Lets say I have 3 tables:

- Customers
- Orders
- Products

I want to retrieve a list of customers and their orders with some filtering on some Customers' and orders' fields and return a graph that only shows basic informations of each entities.
For instance, a Customer could have 19 fields but I only want to read it's ID, FirstName, LastName and from the orders, I only want to read the NetPrice and the related product IDs in a way that when the iteration occurs on the query, the SQL that gets generated is very lightweight and will only select those specific fields.
Is it something that can be achieved? If so, how? I'm very puzzled on how to do this.
Thank you very much.

EDIT:
Ok, I've managed to do it and boy it's fast now!!
Here's how I did it:

```
var customers = (from customer in Context.Cutomers
                select new
                {
                    customer.ID,
                    customer.FirstName,
                    customer.LastName,
                    Orders = customer.Orders.Select(order => new
                    {
                        order.ID,
                        order.NetPrice,
                        Products = order.Products.Select(product => new
                        {
                            product.ID
                        }
                    }
                })
                .AsEnumerable()
                .Select(c => new Customer 
                {
                    c.ID,
                    //In my case, this is VERY important as it will 
                    //try to convert from IEnumerable<T> to ICollection<T> 
                    //which seems to need to be explicit.
                    Orders = c.Orders as ICollection<Order> 
                })
                .ToList();
```

EDIT #2:
I was wrong... It compiles fine, everything seems to be working but, my products are empty...
I'm stumped again...

Answer (score 0):

You can use projection (either to annonymous or prepared type). I didn't try it but I think somethink like this should work:

```
var query = from c in context.Customers
            select new 
              {
                 c.Id,
                 c.FirstName,
                 c.LastName,
                 Orders = c.Orders.Select(o =>
                   new OrderPartial
                     {
                       NetPrice = o.NetPrice,
                       ProductIds = o.Products.Select(p => p.Id) 
                     })
              };
```